# Convert a 1X9 array to a 9X1

Tags: matlab

I want to substract two arrays in Matlab but they are of different sizes. When I try to substract them, it says the following:

```
??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree
```

Does anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If the arrays are of different sizes, what should the size of the result be?

Comment: its telling you the arrays are of diffrent sizes... thats what the error is, please show us what you have (the two arrays with actual data) and what it is you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jens Björnhager is correct: the `transpose()` function will do what you want, which is to flip one of your input vectors from a row-vector to a column-vector.

Alternately, Use the `'` operator. `A'` is shorthand for `transpose(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `transpose()` function to make the sizes match.